# Show that the function is not continuous in point $x_{0}=0$

Tags: derivatives, continuity

I should show that $f':\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is not continuous at the point $x=0$, where $$ x \mapsto \begin{cases} 2x \cos{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}+\sin{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)} &  ,x\neq 0 \\ 0 & ,x=0 \end{cases}$$

---

My idea is to show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f'(x) \neq f'(0)$. I have $f'(0)=0$, and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(2x \cos(\frac{1}{x})+\sin(\frac{1}{x}))=\infty$.  But i am not sure if this is correct. If it is not correct, why not ? And how can i show it than ?

Comment: You have to take the limit at $0$, not at infinity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** on a metric space, a function $g$ is continuous at $x_0$ if and only if $g(x_n)\longrightarrow g(x_0)$ whenever $x_n\longrightarrow x_0$.

Let's try the points $x_n=\frac{2}{(2n+1)\pi}$. Of course, $x_n\longrightarrow 0$. Now
$$
f'\left( \frac{2}{(2n+1)\pi}\right)=\frac{4}{(2n+1)\pi}\cos\left( \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}\right)+ \sin\left( \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}\right)=(-1)^n.
$$
Since it admits two subsequences converging to two distinct limits $\pm 1$, $f'(x_n)$ does not converge to any value. In particular, it does not converge to $f'(0)=0$.

So $f'$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: How do you get $x_{n}=\frac{2}{n*\pi}$. Do i have to take the limit at $0$ or $\infty$ ? So now i have $2(\frac{2}{n*\pi})\cos{(\frac{n* \pi}{2})}+\sin{(\frac{n*\pi}{2})}$

Comment: @Devid You need to look at sequences $x_n$ which tend to $0$. I have updated. The best choice is $\frac{2}{(2n+1)\pi}$. It is a good choice because it makes the computation of the cos and the sin easy.

Comment: ok so the point here is to find a sequence which tends to 0. So the way i wanted to prove it won't actually work right ?  It is just that it is hard to find a sequnce.

Comment: @Devid It is just much easier to do it with sequences than with arbitraray $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ neighborhoods. And this choice of sequence is very natural given the function.

Comment: ok thank you very much, could you also show me the definition you used here (wikipedia).

Comment: @Devid Try to read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function. The keyword is "sequentially continuous", which is the same as "continuous" on a metric space.

Comment: Me again, i just have one more question. In my first post i did a mistake, it should be with a limit to $0$. So actually just saying that $lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\sin{(\frac{1}{x})}$ does not exists and therefore  $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f'(x)$ is not equal to $f'(0)$ is not correct. But why is this not correct ? Can you explain this ?

Comment: @Devid Simply because $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\sin (1/x)$ is not the same thing as $\lim_{\rightarrow 0}\sin (1/x)$...Here, you are looking at the latter. Not the former.

Comment: Oh i did i mistake i meant $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}sin{(\frac{1}{x})}$ in the above question.

Comment: @Devid $f'(x)$ is made of two pieces. The lhs term tends to $0$ at $0$. So indeed it boils down to showing that $\sin (1/x)$ does not have a limnit when $x$ tend to $0$. Again, the sequential way is the easier way. As you need to prove it.